# Sending email form with php

Tags: php, forms, email

I've got a [page](http://www.bendana.it/it/acquisti.php) in which you can calculate pieces and prices, and I'd like to send the result as an email.
This is the function form:

```
    function formulario()
    {if(!isset($_POST['invia']))

    echo "<div id=\"form_wrapper_wrapper\">
    <div id=\"form1\">
        <h1>CONTATTI</h1>
        <form name=\"contatti\" action=\"acquisti.php\" method=\"post\">
            <table>
                <tr><td>nome e cognome/ditta*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"ditta\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo nome e cognome, o il nome della tua ditta\"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>p.iva*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"piva\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui la tua partita IVA\"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>c.f.*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"cf\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo codice fiscale\"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>referente (come sei venuto a conoscenza di Bendana)</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"ref\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui come sei venuto a conoscenza di Bendana (facoltativo)\"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>email*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"email\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo  indirizzo e-mail\" required></td></tr>
                <tr><td>indirizzo*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"via\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo indirizzo\" required></td></tr>
                <tr><td>cap*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"cap\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo paese\" required></td></tr>
                <tr><td>città</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"citta\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui la tua città\"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>telefono</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"tel\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo numero di telefono\" required></td></tr>
                <tr><td>fax&nbsp;</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"fax\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo numero fax\"></td></tr>
            </table>
            <p id=\"obbligatorio\">I campi contrassegnati con l'asterisco sono obbligatori.</p>
    </div>
    <div id=\"form2\">
            <table>
                <tr><td></td><td><input id=\"cancella\" type=\"reset\" name=\"cancella\" value=\"Cancella\"><input id=\"invia\" type=\"submit\" name=\"invia\" value=\"Invia\"></td></tr>
            </table>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>";}
    include('acquisti1.php');
    include('acquisti2.php');
    include('acquisti3.php');
    include('acquisti4.php');
    include('acquisti5.php');
    include('acquisti6.php');
    include('acquisti7.php');
    include('acquisti8.php');
    include('acquisti9.php');
    {"
    </form>"; }
```

Problem is, when I decide the quantities (for now the table **modello 001** is the only one that works) I'm resent to the compilation of the personal infos form, like if the two forms were dependent each other. How can I do the calculation indipendently, and then, once the personal info form is filled, click on "**invia**" to send the mail?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the form just store the values the form calculates and send those.

Comment: How can I store the values?

Comment: Let the user use the calculator, and after they submit the data use the $_POST to read the data the user submitted. Give this a read: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp